# What's the last thing I typed in the console?

Tags: javascript

If I'm in my browser's JavaScript console, how can I programmatically get the last line I typed into the console?

I want to use this so that when I'm messing around with a DOM interactively using the JS console, I can have a `savethat()` function and if I like what I typed I can say

```
savethat(whatIjusttyped);
```

Let me try one more time:

In a pure JavaScript REPL environment, what expression will **evaluate to** the last console user input?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, but you can use the "up" arrow to go through your command history...

Comment: For some reason at least three people have failed to read the OP -- it says "programmatically" and gives an explicit example of what that means.

Comment: I don't understand why this OP has gotten 4 downvotes and 2 closevotes in 30 seconds. It's a good question stated well.

Comment: -1, you didn't specify the browser. also read its manual.

Comment: -1 for being unclear; I still can't tell if you want an expression that will evaluate to the value that the last entered expression evaluated to, or an expression that will evaluate to the last expression you entered as a string. For example, if you just typed `2+2`, do you want an expression that evaluates to `4` or to `'2+2'`?

Comment: What exactly would you expect `savethat()` to do? you're question is very unclear. What are you expecting to get out of the code you posted in your question?

Comment: They’re all different, so please specify which REPL. Also, do you want the previous input as a string, or the result given by evaluating the previous expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the result (value) of the last typed expression. To do that use `$_` variable.

[image: screenshot]

I'm not sure you can get a line itself using JS, but you can do it using built-in feature of console itself - just press up button to modify the last entered *line*.

If you really want to access that line programmatically, you should understand there is no standard-defined way of doing that (ECMAscript certainly doesn't say how to do it). You should refer to your browser JS implementation documentation and hopefully you find something...

Comment: "whatIjusttyped" is not the last expression. Let alone the _value_ of the last expressions...

Comment: +1 for mentioning `$_` and causing me to google that with bing and subsequently discover the Chrome's [CommandLine API Reference](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api) and the complementary [Console API Reference](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api).  What good stuff!